# Matrix diagonal zeroes

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

So i have to print the number of diagonals containing  only zeros in a matrix.
I have done it by the reverse diagonal , but not by the main. I just can't figure it out. so this is what i have done so far:

```
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int n,b=0;
cin>>n;
int a[n][n];
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    cin>>a[i][j];
}
int j,i;
for(int br=0; br<2*n-1; br++)
{


   if(br<n) {
      i=br;
     j = 0;
   }
   else {
      i = n-1;
     j = (br+1)%n;
   }
   bool p=1;
   while(i>=0 && j<n)
   {

    if(a[i][j]!=0)
        { p=0;
        break;}
      i--;
     j++;
   }
   if(p)
    b++;
 }

cout<<endl;
cout<<b;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it obvious? Add another loop:

```
for(int br=0; br<2*n-1; br++)
{
  if(br<n)
    {
      i=n-br-1;
      j = 0;
    }
  else
    {
      i = 0;
      j = (br+1)-n;
    }
  bool p=1;
  while(i<n && j<n)
    {
      if(a[i][j]!=0)
        {
          p=0;
          break;
        }
      i++;
      j++;
    }
  if(p)
    b++;
}
```

(I've left in some questionable things like `bool p=1;` to make the parallel clearer.)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this is not valid C++:

```
cin>>n;
int a[n][n];
```

n should be a compile time constant. Else use a vector of vectors.

Secondly, if you have to traverse all the diagonals, then you should have four sets of nested for loops:

```
for ( int row = 0; row < n; row++ )
  for ( int r=row,col=0; r < n && col < n; ) { col++; r++;/*...*/}

for ( int col = 0; col < n; col++ )
  for ( int c=col,row=0; row < n && c < n; ) { c++; row++;/*...*/}

for ( int row = 0; row < n; row++ )
  for ( int r=row,col=0; r >= 0 && col < n; ) { col++; r--;/*...*/}

for ( int col = 0; col < n; col++ )
  for ( int c=col,row=0; row < n && c >= 0; ) { c--; row++;/*...*/}
```